# Javas Class<?> equivalent in C++

Tags: java, c++

So I'm learning C++ and want to write an entity-component system. For that I need to know what type a component has when i add it to the entity. In java i would just do something like this:

```
Class<?> someClass = myComponent.class;
```

Is there something equivalent I can do in C++? I tried typeid(myComponent) but that doesn't work in situations like this.

```
ExtComponent* extended = new ExtComponent();
Component* base = dynamic_cast<Component>(extended);
std::cout << typeid(base).name();
```

This returns "class Component" but i would want something that returns "class ExtComponent" in such a situation. How do I do this.

Comment: What you want is `std::cout << typeid(*base).name()`.  base is a `Component*`, and will never change.  What base points to can change types, based on the underlying virtual type.  Also, your dynamic cast requires a `dynamic_cast<Component*>`

Comment: You don't need dynamic_cast to upcast. `Component* base = extended;` is sufficient.

Comment: @qwipo happy to help. Other things to note are: Creating a dynamic object with `new` is rarely a good idea. Prefer automatic variables.  Also, `type_info::name` returns an implementation defined string. It could be "class ExtComponent" or it could be "_ZN9ExtComponent" or anything else. You cannot rely on the string being identical across different compilers, or that the name is easily readable.

Comment: You are confusing `TypeName.class` and `referenceVariable.getClass()`. Only the latter is capable of returning the actual type of a Java object.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand you correctly you want to get *dynamic type* of object. (not type of variable itself, but to what that variable (*really*) refers)

Typeid will work because:

N3337 5.2.8/2:

> When typeid is applied to a glvalue expression **whose type is a polymorphic class type** (10.3), the result refers
>   to a std::type_info object representing **the type of the most derived object** (1.8) (**that is, the dynamic
>   type**) to which the glvalue refers[...]

So, just add some virtual function (of alternatively virtual base class) to make, and their will do what you want.

Also you'll have to apply `typeid` to object, not pointer (because that would return `type_info` for pointer, not object):

```
Base *b = new Base;
...
typeid(*b); //not typeid(b)
```

Comment: N3337? Why not [N4594](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/raw/master/papers/n4594.pdf)?

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with types, everything must be resolved at compile time. You can't resolve them at runtime. That's how C++works. To do things that change the type of an expression, you have to deal with templates.

If we want to make a container that store a bunch of instance of various types, you need a way to remember which type it was. Since template instantiate a different function with each one their own address, we can use it to generate a unique id for a type:

```
template<typename>
void type_id(){}

using type_id_t = void(*)();
```

Now, you can use this to store and retrieve in a safe way. Here I will use `std::any`, but you can replace it by `boost::any` if you don't have access to C++17 features.

```
struct Entity {
    template<typename T>
    void assign(T component) {
        components[type_id<T>] = component;
    }

    template<typename T>
    T& retrieve() {
        return std::any_cast<T>(components[type_id<T>]);
    }

private:
    std::map<type_id_t, std::any> components;
};
```

Here you go. You can try out your entity like this:

```
Entity entity;

entity.assign(MyClass{});

MyClass& mc = entity.retreive<MyClass>();
```

This is a rubbish and simple implementation of entities. Usually, you try to keep entities and components packed into memory, and manage the lifetime of them using an entity manager.